# Copying all the cpp files in a Makefile using VSCode Terminal does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile in VS Code but I don't want to lose time writing all of the .cpp files that I have .

A solution for that , which works on Unix is

```
 echo *.cpp > Makefile
```

However when I try this command line in the terminal of VS code, it doesn't work .  I get `*.cpp` in my Makefile

Comment: That can't possibly work as-is on UNIX.  That gives you a file named `Makefile` containing a list of source files... but that's not a valid makefile.  In any event, the "terminal of VS code" is a Windows cmd.com or powershell shell and it is totally different than a UNIX shell and the same commands don't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Make file exemple:

```
NAME     = my_project

IDIR     = include/
IDIR_MY  = ./include

CC       = g++
CFLAGS  += -I $(IDIR) -I $(IDIR_MY)
CFLAGS  += -W -Wall -Wextra

SRCS_DIR        = src/
SRCS_FILES      = *.cpp

SRCS     = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), $(SRCS_FILES))

OBJS     = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
RM       = rm -f

all: $(NAME)


$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)

gdb:    $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g -o debug ./*.cpp -I $(IDIR)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

and for lunch this say just "make" in your term

Comment: you never have any `.o` file, so why depend on `$(OBJS)`